# Discovery of Dynamic library dependency on Mac OS & Linux

Tags: windows, linux, macos, dependencies

On Windows there is a tool Depends.exe to discover dependency of an EXE/DLL file on other DDLs. Which commandline tool is equivalent on Mac OS and Linux?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

- Mac OS X: `otool` `-L` *file*
- Linux: `ldd` *file*

If those commands don't provide what you want, on Mac OS X you can dump all the load commands with `otool` `-l` *file*.  On Linux you can dump the entire contents of the dynamic section with `readelf` `-d` *file*.

Comment: What about static libraries?  I tried `otool -L` but all that does is list a bunch of .o files that are used to build the library.

Comment: @user3055655: Dynamic library dependencies are created when linking.  Because a static archive library has not been linked yet, it would not have any dynamic library dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try MacDependency (https://github.com/kwin/macdependency) which provides an UI replacement for otool on MacOS X. It shows complete dependency trees and the exported symbols as well.

Answer (score 6):

try ldd  in the terminal. This will provide you a list of dynamic libraries that the binary needs.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! It was as simple as:
ldd /path/to/executable_or_dylib

and the verbose version:
ldd -v /path/to/executable_or_dylib

Comment: It runs perfectly for executables. When I run ldd aDynamicLib.so in Ubuntu 9.04, it says: "not a dynamic executable". How to discover dependencies of a .so file? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can put something like following into your bashrc so that you can always use "ldd" as interface but it will redirect macos equivalent one if machine is mac.

```sh
# Macos equivalent of ldd
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ "darwin"* ]]
then
  alias ldd="otool -L"
fi
```