# Dependency resolution in Linux

Tags: c, linux, executable, dependency-resolution

Under Windows, I have used a program called Dependency Walker to examine the libraries the application uses. I was wondering how I can achieve this on Linux for a standard binary:

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.0, stripped

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057234/discovery-of-dynamic-library-dependency-on-mac-os-linux

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
ldd executable
```

For example:

```
[me@somebox ~]$ ldd /bin/ls
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f57000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7f4c000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xb7f32000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0xb7f2b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7ddc000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7dc4000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f58000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7dc0000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0xb7dbb000)
[me@somebox ~]$
```

Note that this will only report shared libraries.  If you need to find out what static libraries were linked in at compile time, that's a bit trickier, especially seeing as your executable is 'stripped' (no debugging symbols).

Answer (score 5):

Use `ldd`

```
ldd /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want something a little less raw than iteratively calling ldd and somewhat more like MSVC depends, you should try [Visual-ldd](http://freshmeat.net/projects/visual_ldd/).  It hasn't been updated in 4 years, but it should still work given that the ELF format hasn't changed.  It still won't show you individual symbols inside those libraries - for that you'll need something like [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm), and I don't know of any GUI wrapper for that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ldd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd). It will show the dynamic libraries the binary needs.

Note that the libraries themselves may in turn need more libraries. To get these, you can run ldd on the libraries you got from running ldd on the binary.