# cmake: figuring out which libraries is a binary target linked against

Tags: shared-libraries, cmake

I wand to implement in CMake a functionality that would enable the installation of a single binary/target through a `make install-TARGET` command. This is fairly straightforward to do with a custom target. However, when the target binary in question is linked dynamically against other libs of the project (`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`), I need to install the receptive libs as well. Is there any way to somehow query the list of libraries?

I've looked at the target properties, but haven't found anything relevant.

Tips on how to get the list of libs and/or other ways to implement the above described functionality would be very much appreciated!

*[Edit]*

**Example:**
Let's assume that there the project `MyProj` has a CMake target "myprog" which generates the binary `myprog`. I want to install *only* this binary with `make install-myprog`. However `myprog` links against `libmy1.so` and the latter links against `libmy2.so`, both part of `MyProj`. 
I need a mechanism to figure out that I need to install both `libmy1.so` and `libmy2.so` along `myprog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution seems to be the following. One has to use the CMake COMPONENT parameter of the [install command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3ainstall) to assign each install target to a component. For example in the question this would be something like this:

```
install(TARGETS myprog DESTINATION ${BIN_DEST_DIR} COMPONENT myprog),
```

and similarly for the shared libraries

```
install(TARGETS my1 my2 DESTINATION ${LIB_DEST_DIR} COMPONENT my-libs).
```

Now, to invoke the installation of `myprog` as well as `mylib1` and `mylib2` a custom target has to be created that uses the `cmake_install.cmake` locate in the build tree:

```
add_custom_target(install-myprog
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCOMPONENT=my-libs -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCOMPONENT=myprog -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
   COMMENT "Installing myprog").
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do *nix development, but the functionality you're looking for is same as "Dependency Walker" for windows. A quick search brought up the following:

[Dependency resolution in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120796/dependency-resolution-in-linux)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really, I think you misunderstood the question. See the edit above.