# How do you parse optimized/debug library strings in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Certain CMake built in modules, such as `FindPythonLibs`, set some variables that will contain a list of libraries, so that you have a set of libraries for both debug and release build.  When you print one of these, it looks something like `optimized;C:\foo\python27.lib;debug;C:\foo\python27_d.lib`

Now, at least on Windows, there is only one version of python you can link against -- the one that matches your build configuration.  If you're building Debug, you *must* link against debug python, and similarly for release.  So it makes little sense for me to deal with these multiple values when only one is relevant.  So I have two questions:

1. If I just pass this string as is to target_link_libraries(), will it always just choose the right one depending on my `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?
2. Even if it does just figure it out, I still need to extract the path of the one it's going to choose, because I need the path for another purpose.  So, for example, if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, I need the string `C:\foo\python27_d.lib` so I can do something else with it in my script.

How does one usually solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [syntax](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) for `target_link_libraries` you'll see that you pass it extra arguments to indicate optimzied or debug versions of libraries.

The thing to note is that CMake's syntax makes doing `foo(A;B;C)` equivalent to `foo(A B C)`.

So you don't need to parse the string at all; CMake's funny syntax handles it for you: CMake expands the variable value and then expands that into separate arguments to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget ${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES})
```

expands to

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget optimized;C:\foo\python27.lib;debug;C:\foo\python27_d.lib)
```

expands to

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget optimized C:\foo\python27.lib debug C:\foo\python27_d.lib)
```

1. Yep.
2. Off hand I'm not sure of any direct way to ask what version of a particular library is being linked to. Maybe some details on what exactly you're trying to do would suggest a solution. Anyway, perhaps some use of [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) could do what you need, or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929197/365496) could help.

---

I think to copy a file you could use something like:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy C:\foo\python27_d.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mytarget>)
```

I'm still not sure how to go about getting the path to libraries a target depends on.

Comment: Depending on which version is selected to link against, I want to compute the path to the corresponding DLL and copy it to a specific folder.  So if it selects C:\foo\python27_d.lib, I will use a regex replace to compute the string C:\foo\python27_d.dll, and then copy that file to a different place.  But let's say I can figure out which version is selected.  Like somehow I just know it's debug.  Then what's the most elegant way to get key into the list to get the debug library path from this string.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect approach but you may give it a try. Find package for Boost returns a mixed list of requested components. I do exactly what you want for the very same purpose. Perhaps you can adapt it for your needs.

```cs
# GOOD & BAD are single strings, INPUT is a list wrapped in string
# OUTPUT is a name for a list
macro(FILTER_LIST INPUT OUTPUT GOOD BAD)
  set(LST ${INPUT})   # can we avoid this?
  set(PICKME YES)
  foreach(ELEMENT IN LISTS LST)
    if(${ELEMENT} STREQUAL general OR ${ELEMENT} STREQUAL ${GOOD})
      set(PICKME YES)
    elseif(${ELEMENT} STREQUAL ${BAD})
      set(PICKME NO)
    elseif(PICKME)
      string(REPLACE .lib .dll DLL ${ELEMENT})
      list(APPEND ${OUTPUT} ${DLL})
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro(FILTER_LIST)
```

Then you can use such macro like

```cs
FILTER_LIST("${Boost_LIBRARIES}" BOOST_Debug_DLLS debug optimized)
install(FILES ${BOOST_Debug_DLLS} DESTINATION "bin" CONFIGURATIONS Debug COMPONENT Boost)
FILTER_LIST("${Boost_LIBRARIES}" BOOST_Release_DLLS optimized debug)
install(FILES ${BOOST_Release_DLLS} DESTINATION "bin" CONFIGURATIONS Release COMPONENT Boost)
```