# How to find out which files my program depend on?

Tags: deployment, installation, cross-platform, dependencies, packaging

I often run into the problem when I create an installer for my program that I miss out some  files it depend on.

On Windows:

I often miss out some DLL's that are installed on my system. I usually test my installation by just moving the executable in a folder alone to see which DLL's it cry for. But it will use the DLL's it find on my system32 folder anyway - those DLL's maybe there in other users' system, maybe not.

Other way I found that I open the EXE in a hex editor and search for the pattern '.DLL'. But dll's can depend on other dlls too.

Is there a (preferably free) tool that can tell me what DLL's my program need? So I won't miss out anything.

On Linux:

Linuxes have a nice package management system. Making an installer in those systems means making a package for them. I can find out what .so (shared object) files my programs need. But how can I determine which package contains that .SO file so I can add that package as dependency when packaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, what you're looking for is a tool called [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), which tells you what DLLs an EXE (or another DLL) depends on.

On Linux, see [Dependency resolution in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120796/dependency-resolution-in-linux)

Comment: The windows part of the progblem solved.

On Linux I know the ldd utility but I need something that can tell that which package contains that files. Because linux packages need package dependencies not file dependencies.

Comment: @Calmarius each package system has a tool that tells what package contains a particuliar file, it should be a matter of going through the docs. `dpkg` for example has `dpkg -S {/path/to/file}`