# FAISS CGO throwing "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" when using libfaiss_c.a

Tags: go, c++11, cgo, faiss

I am trying to write a self-dependent `go-faiss` wrapper for invoking the KMEANS function of FAISS.
Repo: https://github.com/arjunsk/faiss-cgo-kmeans

This approach is inspired from https://github.com/andyalm/faissmask/tree/master/FaissMask/runtimes

The FAISS static library `libfaiss_c.a` is built using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

When I link that library with CGO, I am getting

Error Log

```
# faiss-go/pkg/ivf.test
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "faiss::Clustering::Clustering(int, int)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "faiss::Clustering::Clustering(int, int, faiss::ClusteringParameters const&)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "faiss::kmeans_clustering(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, float const*, float*)", referenced from:
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "faiss::ClusteringParameters::ClusteringParameters()", referenced from:
      _faiss_ClusteringParameters_init in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::exception_ptr::exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr const&)", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
  "std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      thread-local wrapper routine for faiss_last_exception in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering.cold.1 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::exception_ptr::operator=(std::exception_ptr const&)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering.cold.1 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering.cold.2 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering.cold.2 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::FaissException(faiss::FaissException const&) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::exception::~exception()", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering.cold.1 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::exception::~exception()", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::FaissException(faiss::FaissException const&) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::~FaissException() in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::current_exception()", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "std::rethrow_exception(std::exception_ptr)", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for faiss::FaissException", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table21 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table28 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table29 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table31 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
  "typeinfo for std::runtime_error", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::exception", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table0 in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table21 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table28 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      GCC_except_table29 in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
  "vtable for faiss::FaissException", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::FaissException(faiss::FaissException const&) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::~FaissException() in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for std::exception", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::~FaissException() in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_train in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_kmeans_clustering in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _faiss_get_last_error in libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::runtime_error>(std::runtime_error) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<std::exception>(std::exception) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      std::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr[abi:v15006]<faiss::FaissException>(faiss::FaissException) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      faiss::FaissException::FaissException(faiss::FaissException const&) in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      _faiss_Clustering_new_with_params in libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using these CGO headers

```
/*
#cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../../cgo/thirdparty/runtimes/osx-arm64/native -lfaiss_c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/Clustering_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/impl/AuxIndexStructures_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/index_factory_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/error_c.h>
*/
```

However, this CGO code works when we build `libfaiss_c.dylib` using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` and the `libfaiss_c.dylib` is added to the `/usr/local/lib`. The CGO header would now look like the below

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lfaiss_c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/Clustering_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/impl/AuxIndexStructures_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/index_factory_c.h>
#include <faiss/c_api/error_c.h>
*/
```

Please help me in linking the `*.a` file with CGO from a custom path.

#### Update 1

When I have these files in the `/usr/local/lib`

The test runs
[image]

These files written in the `/usr/local/lib` is created using the below make file

```
GIT_COMMAND ?= git
FAISS_COMMIT ?= d87888b13e7eb339bb9c45825e9d20def6665171

all: faiss

.PHONY: faiss
faiss:
    if [ -e faiss ]; then \
        cd faiss && ${GIT_COMMAND} fetch origin && git reset --hard  $(FAISS_COMMIT); \
    else \
        ${GIT_COMMAND} clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss.git && cd faiss && git reset --hard  $(FAISS_COMMIT); \
    fi
    cd faiss && \
        export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas:/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp:/opt/homebrew && \
        cmake -B build -DFAISS_ENABLE_GPU=OFF -DFAISS_ENABLE_C_API=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DFAISS_ENABLE_PYTHON=OFF . && \
        make -C build && \
        sudo make -C build install && \
        sudo cp build/c_api/libfaiss_c.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfaiss_c.dylib
```

#### Update 2

For the go-rocks db library,
https://github.com/linxGnu/grocksdb#build

they also recommend installing/building the rocksdb library locally and linking that with the cgo interface.

Will this approach of building static library "*.a" independently and shipping it as a self-contained library work?

#### Update 3

#### Go version

```
$ go version
go version go1.20 darwin/arm64
```

#### Operating system and Processor architecture?

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/me/GolandProjects/0learning/faiss-cgo-kmeans/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

#### Update 4

Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321095/1609570

```bash
➜  native git:(master) otool -L libfaiss_c.a
Archive : libfaiss_c.a
libfaiss_c.a(AutoTune_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(Clustering_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexFlat_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexIVFFlat_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexIVF_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexLSH_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexPreTransform_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(VectorTransform_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexShards_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexReplicas_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(Index_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexBinary_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(IndexScalarQuantizer_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(MetaIndexes_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(clone_index_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(error_impl.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(index_factory_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(index_io_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(AuxIndexStructures_c.cpp.o):
libfaiss_c.a(distances_c.cpp.o):
➜  native git:(master)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ldd <Binaryname>` when you try building it with the shared library ?

Comment: In addition to this, I notice that you mentioned you build libfaiss_c.a using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. Did you by any chance miss `-DFAISS_ENABLE_C_API=ON` ?

Comment: @HarishGanesan No, I did not miss out on `-DFAISS_ENABLE_C_API=ON`. I just skipped it for brevity.

Comment: @HarishGanesan I added the details in Update 4 section.

Comment: The Update 4 is now just showing the contents of the archive. I requested the libraries which the binary was linking to, when it was able to build properly. Also I see that it is complaining about missing symbols like `operator new`. You might want to take a look at how the .a file was built again.

Comment: Also, you might wanna take a look at this issue https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/1783#issue-840932980.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @HarishGanesan for pointing out that [FAISS c_api depends on FAISS](https://github.com/eugenehp/faiss-mobile/issues/1), which also needs to be included for static linking.

After looking into the implementation of [c-rocksdb](https://github.com/cockroachdb/c-rocksdb/tree/master#rocksdb) by `CockroachDB`, I found that some of the extra flags could help in resolving the `undefined symbols for architecture arm64` error

```
/*
#cgo CPPFLAGS: -Ithirdparty/libfaiss-src/c_api
#cgo CFLAGS: -Ithirdparty/libfaiss-src/c_api
#cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -Lthirdparty/runtimes/osx-arm64/native -lfaiss_c -lfaiss -lomp
#cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup
#cgo !darwin LDFLAGS: -Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-all

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Clustering_c.h>
#include <impl/AuxIndexStructures_c.h>
#include <index_factory_c.h>
#include <error_c.h>
*/
```

This code currently works on both the Macbook M1 chip and the M2 chip.

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/arjunsk/faiss-cgo-kmeans).

#### Update 1

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/c-forestdb

https://github.com/cockroachdb/c-rocksdb

These projects are good reference point for doing the static linking for external c libraries.